# Stop flexbox item "flex:1" from taking more space caused from the width of the children

Tags: css, flexbox, width

I have the following html/css. Which renders like this:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.one {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  /* width: 100px; <-- this is what I'd like to achieve */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  width: 150px; /* <-- this is bigger than width of .parent */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see the `div` with `.inner` is `150px` causing its parent div, with flex: 1, to take more space.

What I'd like to achieve is this:

[image]

I know the existence and tried to use, `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink`. I couldn't make it work.

The question: is there a way to make it work using only flexbox?

Comment: min-width: 0; to the two

Answer (score 0):

Easily managed with `position: relative` one `two` and `position:absolute` on `inner`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.one {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  /* width: 100px; <-- this is what I'd like to achieve */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  position:absolute;
  width: 150px; /* <-- this is bigger than width of .parent */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Only using `max-width:50%` on class `two`

DEMO 2

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.one {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

.two {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  /* width: 100px; <-- this is what I'd like to achieve */
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inner {
  width: 150px; /* <-- this is bigger than width of .parent */
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. However, is there a way to make it work using only flex-shrink/flex-grow? i.e. isn't shrink/grow meant for this kind of scenarios?

Comment: Please check Demo 2, I made it just by adding: `max-width: 50%;` on class `two`. Just with flex, you wont be able